# grunt-imagine sprite task failing

Tags: gruntjs, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to do dev work on a site. Up until today I had been using grunt installed locally on my machine (my local `~/dev/websites/[project]` folders were mapped to `/websites/[project]` in the Vagrant vm), and it works just fine. I finally got around to installing node, npm, and grunt in my Vagrant vm so I could run `grunt dev` tasks from within the vm, rather than my own system. My `Gruntfile.js` contains this section, calling `grunt-imagine`:

```
sprites: {
    main: {
        src: ['<%= config.path.sprites %>/*.png'],
        css: '<%= config.path.sass %>/components/_sprites.scss',
        map: '<%= config.path.spritesbuild %>/sprites.png',
        output: 'scss',
        dimensions: true,
        classPrefix: 'sprite',
    }
}
```

Works great...when I run grunt from my local computer. When I run from within the vagrant VM, I get this error:

```
Running "sprites:main" (sprites) task
[D] Task source: /websites/[project]/node_modules/grunt-imagine/tasks/sprites.js
Verifying property sprites.main exists in config...OK
Files: public/assets/sprites/1.png, public/assets/sprites/2.png, public/assets/sprites/3.png, public/assets/sprites/4.png
Fatal error: Unexpected end of input
```

That's with the debug and verbose flags on. Bear in mind *the task file in the vm is literally the exact same file as outside the vm*, which tells me something's probably not installed correctly. But grunt should be using all the same files, right? Why might this work on my local machine but not in my dev environment?

ETA: If it matters (and it might) my local machine is running OS X Yosemite, and my Vagrant dev box is Debian Wheezy. Binary problem between Mac and Linux?

Comment: There's an extra `,` after classPrefix, not sure if that's the cause for failure though.

Comment: That's because there are a few more lines underneath that line that aren't strictly relevant to the question here, and I forgot to remove the trailing `,` when I pasted the code here. Call it an artifact of anonymization.